# How do I use the result of a Java function in Scala?

Tags: java, scala

I have a Java function that returns an object built by a Scala function. The Java function looks like this

```
import frontEnd.Builder ;
import frontEnd.AST.DeclList ;

public class Parser { 
    Builder builder  ;
    public DeclList Start() {
        DeclList result=builder.declList() ;
        ...
        return result ; } }
```

where `AST` is a trait, `Builder` is a class that extends `AST` and `DeclList` is a trait. `builder.declList` returns a value of type `builder.DeclList`.

(This seems complicated, but it all compiles, and I think it makes sense. I'm happy to change it if that helps.  In particular, I suspect that, if I could eliminate the use of path dependent types, the problem below would not be.)

So far, so good.  The problem is when I call `Parser.Start` from Scala code, the result has type `<none>` or `<notype>` depending which error message I choose to believe.   Here is the Scala code that calls start.

```
val p : Parser = new Parser( stream )
val builder = new frontEnd.Builder() ;
p.setBuilder( builder )
val dl : builder.DeclList = p.Start()
```

The last line has an error message of

```
../src/tests/ParserTests.scala:19: error: type mismatch;
found   : <notype>
required: builder.DeclList
    val dl : builder.DeclList = p.Start()
                                       ^
one error found
```

Comment: Try

    `val dl : frontend.AST.DeclList = p.Start()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Sri Harsha Chilakapati's suggestion I tried

```
val dl : frontend.AST.DeclList = p.Start()
```

But this was in error because `AST` had no companion object. So I created one and changed the builder to use (rather than extend) `AST`. Thus I had no more path dependent types.  (I hadn't actually wanted them to start with, so that was ok.) Now the error message was

```
 found   : frontEnd.AST#DeclList
 required: frontEnd.AST.DeclList
    val dl : frontEnd.AST.DeclList = p.Start()
                                            ^
```

Finally I changed the line to

```
val dl : frontEnd.AST.DeclList = p.Start().asInstanceOf[frontEnd.AST.DeclList] ;
```

This compiled. And ran.

I had tried to use `asInstanceOf` earlier, but this had not worked, as `<notype>` did not have the `asInstanceOf` method.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is there is no type named `DeclList` in the package `builder`. That type exists in `frontend.AST` package as per your java class definition. So change the last line to

```scala
val dl : frontend.AST.DeclList = p.Start()
```

Comment: That almost did it. See my answer below.

Comment: Where's your answer? I can't see one

Comment: It's there now.  It took a while to make sure it was running as well as compiling.  Also note that `builder` is not a package, it is an object of class `Builder`, which extends `AST`, which contains `DeclList`, so `builder.DeclList` is actually a type.